Does chanting the Pranava during a ritual without initiation implicitly confer initiation?
Traditionally, the chanting of the Pranava is reserved for those who have undergone formal initiation. However, in certain rituals, participants who have not received such initiation are sometimes guided by a qualified conductor (upasakas) to utter verses that include the Pranava, at least once, as part of the ceremony.
This raises an important question:
Does chanting the Pranava during a ritual, under the guidance of a upasaka, implicitly confer initiation or grant the spiritual authority to recite it independently afterward?

Your question Does chanting the Pranava during a ritual, under the guidance of a upasaka, implicitly confer initiation or grant the spiritual authority to recite it independently afterward?
According to Kulārnava Tantra(कुलार्णव तंत्र) [chapter-14], there are three kinds of Dīksha (दीक्षा/Initiation) as follows:
स्पर्शाख्या देवि दृकसंज्ञा मानसाख्या महेश्वरि ।
क्रियायासादिराहता देवा दीक्षा त्रिधा स्मृता ॥ ३४ ॥ 

Initiation by touch [Sparsa], Initiation by sight [Drksamjnā] and
Initiation by thought [Mānasa] all these three are done without
Rituals and without exertions.॥ 34 ॥

According to sloka [14.34], the difference among three kinds of Dīksha is explained by subsequent three slokas [14.35-37]:

यथा पक्षी स्वपक्षाभ्यां शिशन्‌ संवर्द्धयेच्छनैः ।
स्पर्शदीक्षोपदेशच्च तादृशाः कथितः प्रिये ॥ ३५ ॥
O My Beloved! Initiation and instruction by touch is likened to
the slow nourishing of its young by the bird with the warmth of its
wings. ॥ 35 ॥
स्वापत्यानि यथा मत्स्यो वीक्षणेनैव पोषयेत्‌ ।
दृग्भ्यां दीक्षोपदेशश्च तादृशः परमेश्वरि ॥ ३६ ॥
O Paramesvari! Initiation and instruction by sight is like
nourishing of its young by the fish through its seeing alone. ॥ 36 ॥
यथा कुर्मः स्वतनयान्‌ ध्यानमात्रेण पोषयेत्‌ ।
वेधदीक्षोपदेशश्च मानसः स्यात्‌ तथाविधः ॥ ३७ ॥
Initiation and instruction by thought is like the nourishing of
its young by the tortoise by only thinking. ॥ 37 ॥

While initiation the disciple receives not only blessing but also sakti(शक्ति) as given in the following sloka [14.38]:
शक्तिपातानुसारेण शिष्योनुग्रहमर्हति ।
यत्र शक्ति निपातता तत्र सिद्धिर्वजायते ॥ ३८ ॥

The disciple receives the Guru according to the impact of the Sakti
[Saktipāta]; where there is no impact of Sakti there is no fulfilment.॥ 38 ॥

Beware: Unless disciple receives guru blessings with enough impact of sakti(शक्ति), there is no siddhi (सिद्धि/fulfilment) is possible.
According to Kulārnava Tantra, apart from the three kinds of initiation (with no rituals) as explained by sloka [14.34], it does not support any implicit form of initiation carried out (of course with guidance of an upāsaka) in a ritual. Therefore, Kulārnava Tantra does not authorize to recite (japa) independently afterward because such acts do not constitute as Dīksha. Moreover, sloka [14.34] supports neither rituals nor exertions while initiation.
